# Show that every group of order 48 has a nontrivial normal subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

> Show that every group of order $48$ has a nontrivial normal subgroup.

**Proof**

Let $G$ denote a group of order $48$. Let $P_k$ denote the k-sylow subgroup, and $n_k$ denote the number of conjugates of $P_k$. Let $N(P_k)$ be the normalizer of $P_k$. Then,

$n_3 \equiv 1 \mod 3$ and $n_3 | 16 \implies n_3=1,4,16$

$n_2 \equiv 1 \mod 2$ and $n_2|3 \implies n_2=1,3$

Suppose that $n_3 = 4$ or $16$, and let $n_2=3$ for contradiction.

Then $n_3 = 3 \implies |N(P_3)|=16$. So we have a subgroup of order 16 in $G$.

> There is a theorem in Rotman's textbook (Advanced Modern Algebra):
>
> **(Representation of Cosets).** *If H is a subgroup of finite index n in a group G, then there exists a homomorphism $\phi: G \rightarrow S_n$ with $\ker \phi \subseteq H$*.

Using this theorem for $N(P_2)$, we know that there is a homomorphism $\phi: G \rightarrow S_3$ with kernel in $N(P_2)$. $P_3$ can only be sent to the 3-sylow subgroup of $S_3$, since the image of an element must divide the order of the pre-image. Since the 3-sylow subgroup of $S_3$ is normal, its image must also be normal. So $P_3$ is normal, a contradiction. So $n_2=1$ and we're done.

Do you think my proof is correct?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The subgroups of $S_3$ do not have images inside $G$. They do have *preimages* though. But all the preimages will all contain the kernel of $\phi$, so are likely larger than $P_3$. Apropos kernels, aren't they always normal?

Comment: If you would like to "break a butterfly upon a wheel" you could use the classification of finite simple groups.

Comment: You may want to fix up the notation on the line before the theorem. Also, as Lahtonen said, this doesn't show $P_3$ is normal, but it does show something, what is that?

Comment: @BabyDragon or just the much easier (though still much harder than needed) Burnside's $pq$-theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second to last line is where you reach a problem: We don't have an "image" of $S_3$, we have a pre-image. This pre-image contains $P_3$, but is not in necessity equal to it. In fact, since the Slyow 3-group of $S_3$ contains the identity, the pre-image of the subgroup of $S_3$ contains the kernel, properly. But the pre-image of a normal subgroup is normal. So we must only really show that the pre-image is a proper subgroup.

A simpler proof though, notes that we may let $\phi$ be the representation by conjugation on the Slyow 2-groups (which are of order 16). If this is trivial, then we see that $n_1=1$ by Slyow's Theoroms. If not, then Ker $\phi$ is the desired proper normal subgroup (Since Ker $\phi=0$ makes no sense considering the order).

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I have two questions. 1) If we have a homomorphism $\phi: G \rightarrow S_3$, then  for $x \in G$, the order of $\phi(x)$ must divide the order of $x$, right? So if we let $P_3 = \langle x \rangle$, then the order of $\phi(x)$ must divide 3...so it must be 1 or 3. If it is 3, then I can still use the argument that $\langle \phi(x) \rangle$ has order 3 and is normal in $S_3$ so $\langle x \rangle$ must also be normal. But if $|\phi(x)|=1$, then we run into a problem and my argument doesn't hold. Is that right, because I just want to check if I understood it?

Comment: 2) Is it possible for me say that $\phi : G \rightarrow S_3$ cannot be injective, since $|G|=48>|S|_3 =6$. So the kernel of $\phi$ must be nontrivial...but that just means that we have a nontrivial normal subgroup in G, right?

Comment: The flaw in your first aurgument is that you only know that the pre-image of $<\phi(x)>$ is normal. The pre-image contains the kernal of $\phi$, and since order forces $\phi$ to have a nontrival kernal, things get hazzy. It does contain $P_3$ as a subgroup, but that doesn't force normality, and the pre-image could be the whole group, so we don't really gain much from the argument as it is.

Comment: Your right on two though, since $\phi$ isn't injective, and the kernal is contained in a proper subgroup, so it is a desired nontrivial normal subgroup, which is what we wanted.

Comment: @Artus: $|\phi(G)|$ has order divisible by 3 by Sylow's theorem: $G$ acts transitively on the $n_p$ Sylow $p$-subgroups, so $|\phi(G)|$ is divisible by $n_p$.

Comment: @Artus: Your logic seems to go like: "$\phi(P_3)$ normal" $\implies$ "$P_3$ normal". This is just wrong. You could deduce normality of any subgroup with that method simply by letting $\phi$ be the trivial homomorphism sending everything to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to expand a bit on the specific homomorphism $\phi$ Rotman has in mind: $G$ acts on the left coset space $G/H$ by left-multiplication, which is what induces the homomorphism into $S_n$.

There are 2 things we want to be sure do not happen:

1) That the kernel is trivial. Since the order of $G$ in this case is much larger than $[G:H]!$, this does not happen ($|H| = 16$ and clearly $48 > 6$).

2) That the kernel is not all of $G$ itself (i.e., that the image is trivial). But this is ruled out by the fact that only left-multiplication by elements of $H$ will fix the coset $H$, so the kernel of $\phi$ must be contained within $H$ (and thus, in particular, NOT all of $G$).

So we know $G$ has a proper non-trivial normal subgroup (the kernel of $\phi$), which is all your question asks for (although we do not know if this subgroup is $P_2, P_3$ or $N(P_3)$).

I believe Herstein actually has a theorem that if a finite group $G$ has a subgroup $H$ such that $|G| \not \mid [G:H]!$, then $H$ contains a non-trivial normal subgroup, which is based on the same idea.